# Docker images appear only with IDs

Tags: docker, docker-image

I create and run docker containers.

`docker image ls` shows the following

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
model_cnn3_4                     trained_linux          c29d652864b3        About an hour ago   3.37GB
<none>                           <none>                 72fde1eacaff        4 hours ago         3.37GB
<none>                           <none>                 b1c12b6f4603        21 hours ago        3.37GB
<none>                           <none>                 4815f2e0588e        22 hours ago        3.37GB
<none>                           <none>                 b05ec80bf7ae        24 hours ago        3.37GB
model_cnn3_6                     latest                 c266efd55148        27 hours ago        3.35GB
model_cnn3_4                     latest                 6c6a9e2d0e89        27 hours ago        3.35GB
<none>                           <none>                 9f521f6d9829        43 hours ago        3.35GB
tensorflow-py3-gpu-keras         latest                 172a48e49bf4        43 hours ago        3.35GB
tensorflow/tensorflow            v3                     1ec7a5c316f4        4 days ago          1.67GB
anaconda3-keras-tensorflow-gpu   latest                 239c5ba65421        4 days ago          4.5GB
continuumio/anaconda3            latest                 1cdde60f40a3        2 weeks ago         3.04GB
tensorflow/tensorflow            latest-devel-gpu-py3   83d83027cb5a        2 months ago        3.99GB
tensorflow/tensorflow            latest                 1bb38d61d261        2 months ago        1.21GB
tensorflow/tensorflow            latest-gpu-py3         ae2207c21bc1        2 months ago        3.29GB
```

Where did those images with `<none>` repository and  tag come from?

If I run command `docker run <image ID> ls -la` I can see that these images look like snapshots of containers that have run and stopped some time ago.

But what exactly has created them?

**Update**: `docker run image_tag` does not create new images, right?

Comment: Are you building any Docker images on that host?

Comment: Yes, I have built some images. One of them is running currently (NN training)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a default Docker behaviour.

The  *images* that you are seeing are just the layers used when building a Docker image.

In other words when you build an image few layers get created and stored.

To learn more about it this [blog post](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/) is a good read.

*EDIT*:

No, docker run / start does not create new images, just starts the image you have specified. However, if the image couldn't be located on your hard drive, Docker will go ahead and pull that image for you.

Comment: @wl2776 I've edited my post, in order to answer your last question

Comment: I would kindly ask you to review my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46811493/704329