# Save artifacts from already running docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm completely new to Docker. I'm using it to train neural networks.

I've got a running container, executing a script for training a NN, and saving its weights in container's writable layer. Recently I've realized that this setup is incorrect (I haven't properly RTFM), and the NN weights will be lost after the training finishes.

I've read answers and recipes about volumes and persistent data storage. All of them express one idea: you must prepare that data storage in advance.

My container is *already running*. I understand that incorrect setup is my fault. Anyway, I do not want to lose results that will be obtained during this execution (that is now in progress). Is it possible?

One solution that have come to my mind is to open one more terminal and run  `watch -n 1000 docker commit <image id> tag:label`

That is, commit a snapshot every 1000 seconds. However, weights, obtained on the last epoch are still in danger, since epoch durations differ and are not multiple of 1000.

Are there any more elegant solutions?

Additional information

Image for this container was created using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow-py3-gpu-keras

WORKDIR /root

COPY model4.py /root
COPY data_generator.py /root
COPY hyper_parameters.py /root

CMD python model4.py
```

I have manually created image `tensorflow-py3-gpu-keras` from the latest tensorflow image, pulled from the DockerHub:

`docker run tensorflow`

Inside the container:

`pip3 install keras`

And `docker commit` in another terminal.

Comment: do you need to save the file in the root directory? @wl2776

Comment: Yes, the script is run in /root, and it creates files in current directory

Comment: you could try to mount a directory at that location using -v which will make that directory and all the filed inside permanent

Comment: but not the entire root dir as that wudnt work

Comment: @Matt - no, that's not the case, please,  reread my question and remove flag

Comment: oic. unison or periodic rsyncs are what I would use to do that normally. They will probably be more up to date than infrequent `docker commit`s whcih will  cause a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `docker cp`? That allows you to move files from the Docker filesystem to your host, even if the container is stopped (as long as it hasn't been removed). The syntax would look like the following:

```
docker cp <container id>:/path/to/file/in/container /path/to/file/in/host
```

Comment: I've solved my problem with `docker commit`. But `docker cp` is much better solution. I'll remember it, but hope won't need such hacks anymore.